# Checking for channel telegram subscriptions via python telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I want to make a check for the Telegram channel subscription if the user is subscribed to the channel, the main() function should work if not subscribed to the channel, the main() function should not work

my code works differently even if the user is subscribed to the Telegram channel, the main() function does not work, the else condition works here is my code:

`    import telebot
from telebot import types
import openai
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import textwrap
import os

```
width = 1000
height = 1000
color = (255, 255, 255)  # (R, G, B)
font_size = 24
font = ImageFont.truetype("Roboto-Light.ttf", font_size)

telegram_key = 'TOKEN_BOT'
openai.api_key = 'TOKEN_OPENAI'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(telegram_key)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " Salom! Men - sun'iy intellektman, men misollar va    masalarar yechimini topishda Test yechishda  ishlatishingiz mumkun!\n\n Men kimlar uchun mo'ljallanganman: maktabda yoki institutda o'qidiganlar uchun, chunki har qanday masalada yordam bera olaman.")
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    chanel_id = '-1001896384318'
    # Проверяем, подписан ли пользователь на канал
    # Вам потребуется заменить 'YOUR_CHANNEL_USERNAME' на имя вашего канала
    is_subscribed = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=chanel_id, user_id=user_id).status == 'member'
    
    if is_subscribed:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Вы подписаны на канал и функция main вызвана!')
        # Вызываем функцию main
        main(message)
    else:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Вы не подписаны на канал!')
        main(message)



def main(message):
    img = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), color)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    reply = ''
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine='text-davinci-003',
        prompt=message.text,
        max_tokens=1000,
        temperature=0.9,
        n=10,
        stop=None
    )   
    if response and response.choices:
        reply = response.choices[0].text.strip()
        txt = textwrap.wrap(reply, width=70)

        y = 100  # Initial y-coordinate
        for line in txt:
            draw.text((70, y), line, font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
            y += 30  # Increase the y-coordinate for the next line

        img.save('image.jpg')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open('image.jpg', 'rb'))
        os.remove('image.jpg')
    else:
        reply = 'Oops... something went wrong.'

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, reply)
    pass


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Your function is calling in "else" block, that's why it works if condition is false.
To understand, why function isn't working, if your condition is True add try/except block, like this:

```
try:
    is_subscribed = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=chanel_id, user_id=user_id).status == 'member'
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

There can be some issues with bot permissions, or smth else.